# Reverse geocoding android google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to do reverse geocoding.
I am trying to reverse geocode address "pune railway station".
I am not getting the location from getLocationFromName.

Also, I am trying to search nearby locations for "Pune railway station".
This too is not returning data.

Please is it possible for someone to give me details on
1) how to find the reverse geocode the above ("pune railway station") and
2) find all the nearby location.

Here is the code I am trying to find the nearby location for pune/pune railway station. 
Here 'result' is pune or pune railway station.

```
List<Address> add = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(result, 1);
if (add != null) {
latitude = add.get(0).getLatitude();
longitude = add.get(0).getLongitude();

}
// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GeoCoder",
// Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
addressStr, MAX_RESULTS, latitude - HALF_SIDE,
longitude - HALF_SIDE, latitude + HALF_SIDE, longitude
+ HALF_SIDE); // geoCoder.getFromLocationName(addressStr,
// 5);
if (addresses.size() > 0) {
for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
latitude = addresses.get(i).getLatitude();
longtitude = addresses.get(i).getLongitude();
// Log.v("latlng", "" + i + " " + latitude + " "
// + longtitude);
List<Address> address = null;
try {
/*
* Return 1 address.
*/
address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
longitude, 1);
// if(address == null){
// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
// "Null Final", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// }
try {
// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
// address.size()+" Final",
// Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Address ad = address.get(0);
if (ad.getSubLocality() != null
& ad.getSubAdminArea() != null) {
// if (ad.getSubAdminArea().equals(result))
// {
map.put("area", ad.getSubLocality());
map.put("city", ad.getSubAdminArea());
map.put("latt", "" + ad.getLatitude());
map.put("longg", "" + ad.getLongitude());
location_array.add(map);
// }

}
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.v("Exception e", e.toString());
// if(lat !=0.0 && longg != 0.0){
lat = null;
longg = null;
// }
List<Address> ad = geoCoder
.getFromLocationName(result, 1);
if (add != null) {
lat = ad.get(0).getLatitude();
longg = ad.get(0).getLongitude();
}
}

// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
// "si......." + map.toString(),
// Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
array.add(address.toString());
} catch (IOException e1) {
Log.e("LocationSampleActivity",
"IO Exception in getFromLocation()");
e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
// Error message to post in the log
String errorString = "Illegal arguments "
+ Double.toString(latitude) + " , "
+ Double.toString(longitude)
+ " passed to address service";
Log.e("LocationSampleActivity", errorString);
e2.printStackTrace();
}

// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
// "" + i + " " + latitude + " " + longtitude,
// Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}

} catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks and Regards,
Bhushan

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Pune+railway+station&sensor=false

Comment: Thanks  MaciejGórski. I want to know the 2nd point.How to find out nearby locations for "Pune" or "Pune railway station".

Comment: Here is the code I am trying to get the nearby location for pune/punelocation.